# Spring Boot PropertySources in test environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have an application.properties the values in which I am trying to autoWire in a bean

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationValues {
    @Value("${my.host}") private String myHost
}
```

This works well when I run the application. However When I run a JUnit test, I get an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.host' in string value "${my.host}"
```

And this is my test code

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
public class AnotherDummyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationValues configurationValues;

    @Test
    public void testValue() {
        Assert.assertEquals("localhost", configurationValues.getMyHost());
    }
}
```

This test case fails with the IllegalArgumentException that I mentioned.

Comment: Can you show your `Application.class`?

Comment: Its a plain Java class with just @SpringBootApplication annotation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class,
    initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class AnotherDummyTest {
```

Comment: This worked. But shouldn't this be happening by default. Having the annotation SpringApplicationConfiguration in place of ContextConfiguration  - Shouldn't this add the necessary initializers for me ?

Comment: According Spring Boot docs, it should work without initializer, but I sometimes had problems. To be honest, I didn't dive deeper why as this solves it reliably.